# spring mvc won't connect to mysql database on a different computer

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jdbc

~~~MYSQL NOOB ALERT!!!~~~

I'm trying to connect my Spring MVC project to the sakila schema of the MySQL database on my macbook pro. This same Spring MVC project connects just fine to sakila on my dell desktop, so I suspect I'm missing something in setting up MySQL here.

I've got the server up and running, downloaded MySQL Workbench, made a user and password that match the ones being used by my Spring MVC project, and gave that user all permissions.

Now I"m stuck because I accidentally said that the user could only do 5 queries, when I need infinite, haha.

So how do I:

1) Get past this error message:Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 127.0.0.1:3306:
  User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 5),

2) and how do I add the sakila schema to the particular connection I've created?

Thank you all in advance,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Have A look at this article: [How to modify the ‘max_questions’ resource value in MySQL?](http://www.mkyong.com/mysql/how-to-modify-the-max_questions-resource-value-in-mysql/)
(google "mysql max_questions" third hit!)

The important points are the two commands:

```
update user set max_questions = 0 where user = '<yourLogin>';
flush privileges;
```

`max_questions` is the number of max queries per hour. 0 means no limit.

Comment: That's what I'm confused about. I don't know where I type that in. Like I said, I"m a huge noob at mysql for mac. It's so different from the PC one

Comment: In any SQL Tool (for example MySQL Workbench) that is connected with your Database and of course you must be logged in as mysql admin.